# django registration not loading the registration_complete.html template

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using Django 1.3 and django-registration 0.8. I am trying to use the `RegistrationFormUniqueEmail` class to enforce unique emails.

The form validation works but once the form is submitted, it does not load the `registration_complete.html` template. The page refreshes, and the url goes to `register/complete`, but it just displays an empty `registration_form.html` template.

I suspect my urls.py is incorrectly configured:

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^accounts/register/', 'registration.views.register', {'form_class':RegistrationFormUniqueEmail,'backend':'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend' }),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
```

Any suggestions? I'd prefer not to upgrade Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `$` to the end of your first regex. At the moment, it matches both `/accounts/register/` and `/accounts/register/complete/`.

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'registration.views.register', {'form_class':RegistrationFormUniqueEmail,'backend':'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend' }),
```